# when using testing-library jest runs too many tests...not the ones I want

Tags: node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, testing-library

For some reason I can't seem to split out "cypress, puppeteer and jest unit tests" into separate commands:

package.json:

```
        "test:jest": "jest ./src",
        "e2e:pptr": "npm run dev & jest ./tests",
        "e2e:cypress": "npm run dev & cypress run",
        "e2e:cypress:browser": "npm run dev & cypress open",

...

    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.svelte$": [
                "svelte-jester",
                {
                    "preprocess": true
                }
            ],
            "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
            "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "ts",
            "svelte"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
            "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
        ]
    }
```

WHen I run `npm run test:jest` it still runs all tests. including cypress and `./tests/*.spec.js` files. Its suppposed to just run tests under ./src which are my unit tests.

puppeteer tests are in `./tests/*.spec.js` and cypresss are under `./cypress/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to add `--rootDir <path>` to limit it.

`"test:jest": "jest --rootDir ./src",`